# How to configure remote administration for PC

Tags: networking, home-networking

I'm looking to setup remote administration for my desktop PC.
I'll be away from home and want to access my home desktop for regular maintenance.
I'm using a Wifi router at home for internet access and my desktop PC is behind this router.

Network Setup:-

- From my notebook PC (from which I'll be doing the remote admin), I connect to this router/default gateway (Dlink) using IP address: 192.168.0.1
- For the route admin interface under WAN Settings, I see the settings for router configured as static IP address 192.168.1.12 and ISP gateway address as 192.168.1.1 and some other static addresses for primary and secondary DNS servers.

Please guide on the following :-

- What is the best remote administration software suitable for this setup.
- What address would I need to use to connect to my desktop PC which is behind the router.
- Can Windows standard Remote Desktop do the job for me? If yes, what addresses would I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - What is the best remote administration software suitable for
>     this setup.

If both machines are on Windows I'd just use the regular built-in Remote Desktop Connection. If you don't like the hassle of setting things up, I'd recommend [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com).

> - What address would I need to use to connect to my desktop PC which is
>     behind the router.

Your external IP. You can find out what it is at [whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/). It would be easier to remember a [DynDNS](http://dyndns.com) address though so I'd recommend setting that up. Don't forget the port forwarding in the router to your desktop machine (port 3389) if you use RDC.

> - Can Windows standard Remote Desktop do the job for me? If yes, what
>     addresses would I be using?

Of course it can, although TeamViewer is probably easier. Same address as explained above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. But remote desktop doesn't seem to work.
Using whatsmyip.org on both notebook and desktop PC results in the same IP address (is it that of the router?).And using this IP with remote desktop doesn't work, it won't connect. I have ensured that Remote Desktop is enabled on my desktop PC.

Comment: Having trouble finding port forwarding settings in router settings. Please suggest where it can be found. Under settings for WAN, LAN?

Comment: TeamViewer did the trick! Thanks for the link John.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of responses I left after answering your question. Glad you got things sorted out!